# Find what shared library is making a particular syscall

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, signals, system-calls

At the start of my application I install some signal handlers, but one of the shared libraries I'm linked against is hijacking the handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM. I have confirmed using strace that this is taking place (I can see repeated calls to rt_sigaction). Can someone suggest a way to discover which of the shared libraries is making the rt_sigaction call?

Comment: Use a debugger, set up a breakpoint on the syscall or C library function.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was so far down the rabbit hole I didn't think of the obvious. Using gdb's 'catch syscall' and printing the backtrace has revealed where the calls are coming from.